# GeForce GTX 750 fitting in HP Pavilion p6531p?

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade, nvidia-geforce, hp-pavilion

The tower is a [HP Pavilion p6531p Desktop](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02155335&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=4216475#N185) and the graphics card I'm thinking of buying is a [EVGA GeForce GTX 750](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?gclid=CJHBt-KI-7wCFYhaMgod8C4AdA&Item=N82E16814487027&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-Desktop+Graphics+Cards-_-N82E16814487027&ef_id=Us9RxAAAAFBiYsEF:20140305092139:s).

I've already upgraded the ram and would like to upgrade the video card + power supply as well. What's stopping me is that I'm not too sure if it will fit or not.

What do you guys think?

EDIT: It fit perfectly!

Comment: Have your read your desktop manual or visited the manufacturer website to see if this helps?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams To be honest, I read it but I'm still quite not sure haha. The measurements and the picture both looks like it would fit, but I just wanted to make sure since this is my first time doing this (replacing the graphics card).  
  Anywho, just bought it. Waiting for it to arrive and I'll update here later on. Thanks though @MatthewWilliams!